# Is "I make my hot pizza" the correct way to write "I make my pizza hot"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, word-order

1. I make my pizza hot.
2. I make my hot pizza.

Which sentence is correct?

The first sentence was written by a 7 year old learning English. The second was the "corrected" sentenced written by the teacher. The student does not understand verbs yet.... I was wondering what the teacher was intending to teach with the correction.

Comment: The second is not idiomatic English, at least not in my dialect. The first is odd. It's also necessary to make a pizza hot, since you cook them. I've never heard of a cold brew pizza.

Comment: 'I drink my lemon squash hot' is idiomatic; 'hot' modifies 'my lemon squash' here in a depictive construction.

Comment: The teacher was intending to teach that the teacher is not always right.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that both are grammatically correct. One can make a hot pizza and one can make a pizza hot (by heating it).

I'm also wondering if the teacher was expecting a particular answer based on some other context in the question (which we are not seeing). Perhaps you could add the original question to your post?

If the question was exactly as you posted it, I would criticize the question. Depending on what the speaker is trying to say, either could be correct. Are they saying that they make hot pizza, or are they saying that they induce pizza to become hot (but, perhaps, did not also create the pizza)?